# Why do the element size tooltip and computed style sizes differ in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While I was debugging an issue in my GWT project, I noticed that when I moused over an element, I saw its size in a tooltip and a shaded region indicating its size and position in the screen. However, when selecting that element and viewing its "computed style" attributes, I notice that the width is the same, but the height differs from the tooltip (it is zero).

This makes me wonder: what is the size that Chrome is displaying in the tooltip? Why is it nonzero when the computed style is zero?

Also, the "metrics" region that shows the box model for the element displays a size with a height of zero.

Here is an image about what I am talking about:
http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/1766/96984162.png

Comment: Wow, good question. I'm afraid that looks like a bug or a gotcha in the dev tools. Is it just static HTML in the screenshot, or could perhaps some javascript cause this effect? (i.e. is the height being changed client side or just unchanged after rendering on the server?)

Comment: The height is definitely changing client side via JavaScript. The JavaScript is compiled magic via GWT. Maybe I'll try filing a bug against Chrome and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have an error with your doctype -- this can cause elements to render with an abnormal box model. Tried running your markup through W3C validation? Is there any code that appears before your doctype?

I came across this problem a while back when I accidentally left a print_r() at the beginning of my code.

Comment: I tried changing the doctype, but every doctype I tried other than 4.01 transitional seemed to just break the layouts completely. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip displays the effective offsetWidth/offsetHeight for the inspected element, while the Computed Style displays... well, computed style values for the element. WebKit erroneously returns "0px" instead of "auto" for "display: inline" elements. I guess it still holds for your "display: table-cell" element.

Comment: The Webkit bug has been fixed, now the computed value for width/height in your case should be "auto".